# not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
<h2></h2>
<input type="text" onkeyup="titleb(this.value)">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    (function($){
        function titleb( title ) {
            $('h2').html(title);
        }
    })(jQuery)
</script>
```

It supposed to take the input text and add it to the h2... but what I'm getting instead is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: titleb is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup
```

Comment: The function you are trying is not available at global scope

Comment: oooooh, so how can I fix this?

Comment: Use jQuery to bind event `$('elementSelector').on('keyup', function() { // your code here });`

Comment: That's what I did at first but the keyup was not counting the last character, I read here that on keyup is called later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is nested

This is how to solve this:

```
<h2></h2>
<input type="text" onkeyup="titleb(this.value)">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    let titleb
    (function($){
        titleb = (title) => {
            $('h2').html(title)
        }
    })(jQuery)
</script>
```

For people who don't understand

`(val) => {}` is same as `function (val) {}`

Comment: Could you explain the code please? Or just share a link? I can read about difference between let and var, but what about this: => what is this called? Thank you!!!

Comment: @MonicaLI8 It is as same as mine. The only difference is the fat arrow syntax and let keyword. Any variable defined with let only have a scope of block where it is been created and fat  arrow syntax doesn't require a return keyword.

Comment: @MonicaLl8 I editted my post and explained. Fat arrow,  or `(val) => {}` is same as `function (val) {}`

Comment: @Jai It's not exactly same as yours though.

Comment: @Jai I tried your code but didn't work I'm afraid. Thanks a lot to you both!!

Comment: No problem @MonicaLI8

Answer (score 0):

You can manage to have a namespace like:

```
onkeyup="myapp.titleb(this.value)"
```

and in your script use this:

```
<script>
    var myapp = (function($){
        return function titleb( title ) { // add a return
            $('h2').html(title);
        }
    })(jQuery)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have a function like here.

```js
function titleb(title)
{

  $('h2').html(title);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script><h2></h2>
<input type="text" onkeyup="titleb(this.value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

The function called in the html must be in the global scope like this:

```
<script>
  function titleb( title ) {
    $('h2').html(title);
  }
</script>
```

Here is the working fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/e7z15tqf/